# Testing on staging slot using same config urls as production slot

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, adal, azure-deployment, azure-deployment-slots

I deployed an Angular app to azure with two slots. One is the staging slot and the other is production slot. The idea is to deploy to staging slot, test and ensure that everything works fine and then swap it with the production slot. I am currently using Microsoft ADAL for authentication of users. Is there a way to test my website using same config urls, redirect urls and 'Application settings' of production in the staging slot or do I have to add the staging slot urls in config file separately for staging slot? My staging slot website is https://my-website-staging.azurewebsites.net and my production website is https://my-website.azurewebsites.net. I would like to replicate all the production stuff in stating slot by browsing to https://my-website-staging.azurewebsites.net but I need to configure adal as well. So what is the best to achieve the desired result?

Comment: You need to configure different reply URLs, from AAD's point of view those two are separate apps, although they share a common domain. You *could* configure the reply URL as *.azurewebsites.net, but that would be a **bad** idea.